# How to set text field value position

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I need to render the text field value correctly. I render the text field looks like the following:

```
final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, page.getCropBox().getHeight() - (100 * pdf.getPageNumber(page)), 300, rectHeight);
field = PdfFormField.createText(pdf, rect, name);
field.setFontSize(14);
field.setValue(value);
field.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
form.addField(field, page);
```

and when I'm saving a pdf I have the [image: following] result but when I'm trying to edit the following pdf using Acrobat Reader my text [image: goes down]. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the issue is that usually one sees "Hello" in the text field but when you start editing the field in Acrobat Reader, it all of a sudden becomes "Hello text"?

Comment: @mkl no. When I'm writing in this text word the whole phrase goes down for a couple of pixels.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no *correctly* here, the PDF specification does not prescribe a way to determine the exact height here, merely that the text shall fit in the field given font and font size. Often developers attempt to follow Adobe's lead here but weirdnesses of the fonts in question can still turn out differing results. You may want to share an example form for analysis.